# Laravel 6 passport returns 400 Bad request on wrong credential

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-6

I use Laravel 6 passport **grant password** for my Vue backend.

When i send right credential to **oauth/token** it works and returns token, but when i send wrong (email/password) it returns 400 instead of 401 with this message.

```
    {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.",
    "hint": "",
    "message": "The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
}
```

I checked **client_id** and **client_secret**.

I tested with new installed **Laravel** + **passport** with out single line of code, Laravel 5.8 returns 401 without any problem but Laravel 6 returns 400 bad request.

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: 401 is unauthorized, not a ''wrong credential''

Comment: I know , but in Laravel 5.8 when i provide wrong username/password it returns 401 with this message : invalid_credentials (The user credentials were incorrect) but in Laravel 6 it returns 400 with invalid_grant message
@AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: Did you create your client pair with the `--password` flag in artisan?

Comment: According to Laravel website "If you have already run the passport:install command, you do not need to run this command", but yes i removed them and create new client with --password flag.
@mdexp

Comment: I am encountering the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @NinetyHH I answered what i found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally i found the problem, the problem is back to **league/oauth2-server** which that used by Laravel passport.

They changed response from 401 to 400 in version 8.

[PR link](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/pull/967/commits/2b4974b697ca937d37f407c429d792c467af7ec5)

I changed my code in login section to this.

```
switch ($e->getCode()) {
    case 400:
    case 401:
        return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
    break;
    default:
        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server', $e->getCode());
```

}

Comment: i switched in my own codes, "we usually don't change vendor files...", but if you want know where was the change 
vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Grant/PasswordGrant.php line **107**

`throw OAuthServerException::invalidGrant(); `
change to 
`throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();`
@azurecorn

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Do you know if Is this a known issue or a new way to throw exceptions? Your solution actually does not represent the real response since you won't be able to show "Hey! complete login data!" or "Hey! Your data is wrong!"

Comment: seems it's new way, and it should be 400 regarding this document `https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.2`. If you want separate wrong credential with error, you can create token manually by validating username and password then  `$user->createToken('tokenName')->accessToken` @Luciano

Comment: Tha's correct @Mojtaba Sayari, confirmed by the creators in https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/issues/1093
Thanks for your possible solution BTW

Comment: I sugest you use abort instead of response: `abort($response->status(), 'Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the error handler on **App\Exceptions\Handler**

```
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if (get_class($exception) === OAuthServerException::class) {
            response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rectify
`use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following in laravel 7.x to convert the 400 level error to 401 in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

**NB:** check the `OAuthServerException::class` type

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Exception $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    if (get_class($exception) === \Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException::class) {
        return response(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update UserFactory password (use Hash::make() not bcrypt)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
php artisan passport:keys --force
php artisan passport:client --password
```

then edit your `.env`

```
PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID="Client ID"
PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET="Client secret"
```